# azure build pipeline does not start as triggered

Tags: azure-devops

There is a build pipeline in the Azure git repository:

```
variables:
  BuildConfiguration: release
  BuildPlatform: 'any cpu'
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - release/*
  paths:
    include:
    - src/*
    - azure-pipelines.yml
    - versionFile
```

I'm pushing a local branch to the remote repository using the `push` command like below:

```
git push --set-upstream origin release/0.6.9                                                                                                Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)                                                                                                                      To https://dev.azure.com/*****/**/_git/**                                                                                                     * [new branch]      release/0.6.9 -> release/0.6.9
```

and the new branch appears in the source control.

New branch changes contains files from the `src` subfolder.
The problem is that build won't start.

It should start as [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#behavior-of-triggers-when-new-branches-are-created):

*If your pipeline has path filters, it will be triggered only if the new branch has changes to files that match that path filter.*

There is no space after `release/*` filter as I've just checked.

What can I check additionally ?

**UPD**:
Should all path conditions to be true?

```
  paths:
    include:
    - src/*
    - azure-pipelines.yml
    - versionFile
```

only `src/*` files were changed with the new branch, the `versionFile` and `azure-pipelines.yml` are the same.

UPD2:

there is one more build pipeline to build the documentation

It starts on `git push --set-upstream`

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - release/*
  paths:
    include:
    - doc/*
```

Comment: I've found this note in the docs: `Paths in Git are case-sensitive. Be sure to use the same case as the real folders.` Can you make sure the casing is the same?

Comment: @YanSklyarenko the most weird thing is that `git push --set-upstream` does not start the build pipeline. However `git commit` `git push` starts the pipeline when are performed on  the existing `release/0.6.9` branch (only `src` folder is updated, the build pipeline yml source is not affected and the versionFile is not changed too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've disabled the existing pipeline and created a new one (from the same yml file).

<s>The magic is that it started to work like a charm (I have not overridden the trigger using the pipeline UI)</s>

The existing pipeline can't be deleted since there are releases based on the existing pipeline.

##### UPD

No it does not start to work like a charm. It has happened one time only.

the problem was in the `path` condition `- src/*`
It is not recursive, so is checking for modified files in the  the `src/` folder only and no subfolders are checked.

However the `- src` works fine for all files under `src` folder, like below

```
  paths:
    include:
    - src
```

Answer (score 0):

Test with the same triggers in Yaml file, it could trigger the build successfully.

I would like to share my steps and the possible cause of this issue.

Here are my steps, you could refer to them.

Repo structure：

[image]

Step1: Run Git command to push the changes to new branch.

Commands:

```
git clone "repourlxxx"

git checkout -b release/0.9.7

git add --all

git commit -m "first commit of my code"

git remote add origin xxx

git push --set-upstream origin release/0.9.7
```

**Note:**   When you change the contents of the src folder locally, you need to use `git commit` command to add the changes, and then push to the new branch. Otherwise, there will be no changes in the new branch, so no build is triggered.

Step2: the new branch `release/0.9.7` will be created and the pipeline will be triggered.

[image]

**Note:** The YAML file (azure-pipelines.yml) with triggers needs to be included in the new branch

[image]

**Workaround:**

You could try to use the UI trigger to override the triggers in Yaml code.

Navigate to Settings-> Triggers -> Select `Override the YAML continuous integration trigger from here` option.

[image]

Comment: I have `doc` build pipeline in the same repository that is triggered as it should. I mean that with the same push one pipeline is triggered but another one - not. There are `src` folder changes in the history of `release/0.6.9`

Comment: I ran into a similar problem today. Please check the update, you could try to use the UI page to set the triggers. You can check if it works. This could help us narrow down this issue.